# how to check for valid string input in bash?

Tags: linux, string, bash

code:

```
read location
```

accepted inputs are

```
"/home/(10 chars)" or "/(10 chars)" or "(10 chars)"
```

how to check for valid input? and how to cut the 10 chars from $location variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a grep expression like so:

```
echo $location | grep -xq "\w\{10\}\|/\w\{10\}\|/home/\w\{10\}"
```

This matches lines which are exactly one of the following cases( caused by the -x ) and doesn't print the matching line (caused by the -q)

- 10 characters
- 10 characters with a leading /
- 10 character preceded by '/home/'

To use this in a script, just drop it in an if statement like so:

```
if echo "$location" | grep -xq "\w\{10\}\|/\w\{10\}\|/home/\w\{10\}"; then
    # location valid
else
    # location not valid
fi
```

Comment: please fix the grep solution to `printf '%s' "$input" | tr $'\n' ' ' | grep -q -E '^...$'`. i use `tr $'\n' ' '` to replace every newline with an illegal character. here i assume that space is an illegal character. see also [Check if a string matches a regex in Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112707/check-if-a-string-matches-a-regex-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
case "$location" in
    /home/??????????)
        echo $location
        ;;

    /??????????)
        echo $location
        ;;

    ??????????)
        echo $location
        ;;

    *)
        d=$(dirname "$location")
        b=$(basename "$location")
        echo $d/${b:0:10}
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

You want substitution operators. `${VAR#/home/}` evaluates to the value of `$VAR` with a leading `/home/` stripped, if it exists. By comparing the result of these expressions to `$VAR` itself you can determine whether your value matches, and what the stripped version is. And `${#VAR}` gives you the length of a variable value.